Return Date to Exclude Holiday and Weekend
SQL to return "Date" for EndDate and StartPaymentDate after exclude holiday and weekend.

BufferDate = will default to 3
EndDate = will be day 3 after exclude holiday and weekend
StartPaymentDate = will be day 4 after exclude holiday and weekend
Not able to create weekend and holiday table into 1 table

I tried with this SQL:
DATEADD(day, 3, StartDate) AS DateAdd

Just require simple select dateadd script, not require advance level T-SQL (eg: begin, set, stored procedure).
Holiday table:



Date
Description
Days
Remarks




2024-09-01
Happy New Year
Sunday
Counted in system weekend


2024-09-02
Happy New Year Replacement
Monday
Datedadd = +1


2024-09-05
Holiday 1
Thursday
Datedadd = +1


2024-09-09
Holiday 2
Monday
Datedadd = +1


2024-12-25
National Day
Wednesday
Datedadd = +1


2024-12-25
Christmas Day
Wesneday
Datedadd = 0 (because 2 same holiday falls on weekday will be counted as 1 holiday)


2025-01-01
Happy New Year
Wednesday
Datedadd = +1



This is the output I want to get:



StartDate
EndDate (Day 3)
StartPaymentDate (Day 4)
BufferDate
Remarks




2024-08-30
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
3 (defaulted)
1. 2024-08-30 = Friday = Day 0






2. 2024-08-31 = Saturday (Weekend) no count






3. 2024-09-01 = Sunday (Weekend)  no count






4. 2024-09-02 = Monday (Holiday) no count






5. 2024-09-03 = Tuesday = Day 1






6. 2024-09-04 = Wednesday = Day 2






7. 2024-09-05 = Thursday (Holiday) no count






8. 2024-09-06 = Friday = Day 3 = EndDate






9. 2024-09-07 = Saturday (Weekend) no count






10. 2024-09-08 = Sunday (Weekend) no count






10. 2024-09-09 = Monday (Holiday) no count






11. 2024-09-09 = Tuesday = Day 4 = StartPaymentDate


2024-12-24
2024-12-30
2024-12-31
3 (defaulted)
1. 2024-12-24 = Tuesday = Day 0






2. 2024-12-25 = Wednesday (Holiday) no count






3. 2024-12-26  = Thursday = Day 1






4. 2024-12-27 = Friday = Day 2






5. 2024-12-28  =  Saturday (Weekend) no count






6. 2024-12-29 = Sunday (Weekend) no count






7. 2024-12-30  = Monday = Day 3 = EndDate






8. 2024-12-31  = Tuesday = Day 4 = StartPaymentDate




Please do not delete and repost questions, there is an edit feature.

Is StartDate a single variable or is it multiple values in a table and you need to get all the EndDates and StartPaymentDates for each entry?

With a calendar table, this is trivial work; take the time to invest in one.

A simple solution will be to create a Date table with a flag IsWorkingDay or IsHoliday and then join to that table in your queries and use the IsWorkingDay flag to get next working date.

@ThomA Unfortunately the OP has (again) provided very little information to go on.  My experience is clearly different to yours.  I worked for very many years in finance, where generating good business day date sequences was a permanent requirement.  My predecessors did this with a full calendar table.  I proved however that it was an order of magnitude faster to generate dates in the front end (where weekend checks were trivial) and only using a DB to test for holidays.  So I only ever needed a holiday table.

I don't think that really changes my point, @JonathanWillcock . A (full) calendar table, a holiday table (which is effectively a filtered down calendar table) is what the OP needs here, and that does trivialise the task.

This question is similar to: Add X number of Working days to a date. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JonathanWillcock the startdate could be repeated/multiple entries. Yes, each row require the enddate and start payment. Besides, the holiday table could can change from time to time (based on project). Besides, the startdate could prolong since 2020-01-01 until today's date.

The best way to accomplish this is through the implementation of a calendar table that includes a range of dates, identifies the date type, and assigns sequence numbers that can be used to quickly perform workday calculations. While the initial setup is non-trivial, the payoff can be huge in many types of date operations such as the workday calculations you are trying to accomplish.
Attempting to achieve your goal with an inline expression that handles the general case would be hugely complex if not impossible. Alternatives such a recursive CTE or an on-the-fly candidate-date-generator / workday-count-calculator / result-selector would also be excessively complex and inefficient. (See this recent question for an example of a nearly incomprehensible and highly inefficient implementation resulting from such an attempt.) Neither should be something you would want to implement in production, where others would eventually have to understand and maintain the resulting code in the future.
Go to your boss and tell them the experts say that implementing a calendar table is the best practice for problems such as this.
The following is one possible implementation of a calendar table tailored to the needs of your specific problem. This can be easily expanded to support other uses.
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
    Date DATE NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Calendar PRIMARY KEY,
    IsWeekend BIT NOT NULL,
    IsHoliday BIT NOT NULL,
    IsWorkday BIT NOT NULL,
    DaySequence INT NOT NULL
        INDEX IX_Calendar_DaySequence,
    WorkdaySequence INT
        INDEX IX_Calendar_WorkdaySequence,
    ThisOrPriorWorkdaySequence INT NOT NULL,
    ThisOrNextWorkdaySequence INT NOT NULL,
    -- Additional columns that your application may find useful
    DayOfWeek VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    DayType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Initial range of dates to populate (to be expanded over time)
DECLARE @CalendarFrom DATE = '2024-08-01';
DECLARE @CalendarThru DATE = '2025-01-31';

-- The following are used to accommodate different DATEFIRST settings.
DECLARE @Sat INT = DATEPART(DW, '2000-01-01'); -- Reference Saturday
DECLARE @Sun INT = DATEPART(DW, '2000-01-02'); -- Reference Sunday

INSERT INTO Calendar
SELECT
    D.Date,
    DT.IsWeekend,
    DT.IsHoliday,
    WD.IsWorkday,
    S.Value + 1 AS DaySequence,
    CASE WHEN WD.IsWorkday = 1 THEN SUM(WD.IsWorkday) OVER(ORDER BY D.Date) END
         AS WorkdaySequence,
    SUM(IsWorkday) OVER(ORDER BY D.Date)
         AS ThisOrNextWorkdaySequence,
    SUM(IsWorkday) OVER(ORDER BY D.Date) + 1 - WD.IsWorkday
         AS ThisOrPriorWorkdaySequence,
    DATENAME(dw, D.Date) AS DayOfWeek,
    TRIM(CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN DT.IsWeekend = 1 THEN ' Weekend' END,
        CASE WHEN DT.IsHoliday = 1 THEN ' Holiday' END,
        CASE WHEN WD.IsWorkday = 1 THEN ' Workday' END
        )) AS DayType
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(day, @CalendarFrom, @CalendarThru)) S
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT DATEADD(day, S.value, @CalendarFrom) AS Date
) D
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, D.Date) IN (@Sat, @Sun) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsWeekend,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Holiday H WHERE H.Date = D.Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsHoliday
) DT
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT CASE WHEN DT.IsWeekend = 0 AND IsHoliday = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsWorkday
) WD;

Generated calendar content (in part):



Date
IsWeekend
IsHoli-day
IsWorkday
DaySeq
WorkdaySeq
ThisOrPriorWorkdaySeq
ThisOrNextWorkdaySeq
DayOfWeek
DayType




2024-08-01
False
False
True
1
1
1
1
Thursday
Workday


...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...


2024-08-30
False
False
True
30
22
22
22
Friday
Workday


2024-08-31
True
False
False
31
null
22
23
Saturday
Weekend


2024-09-01
True
True
False
32
null
22
23
Sunday
WeekendHoliday


2024-09-02
False
True
False
33
null
22
23
Monday
Holiday


2024-09-03
False
False
True
34
23
23
23
Tuesday
Workday


2024-09-04
False
False
True
35
24
24
24
Wednesday
Workday


2024-09-05
False
True
False
36
null
24
25
Thursday
Holiday


2024-09-06
False
False
True
37
25
25
25
Friday
Workday


2024-09-07
True
False
False
38
null
25
26
Saturday
Weekend


2024-09-08
True
False
False
39
null
25
26
Sunday
Weekend


2024-09-09
False
True
False
40
null
25
26
Monday
Holiday


2024-09-10
False
False
True
41
26
26
26
Tuesday
Workday


2024-09-11
False
False
True
42
27
27
27
Wednesday
Workday


...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...



The ThisOrPriorWorkdaySequence and ThisOrNextWorkdaySequence columns are present  to support cases where the start date falls on a weekend or holiday and you wish to treat it as the equivalent of the preceding or following workday.
IMPORTANT: After setting up this table, you must also establish a periodic/annual process to extend this calendar as needed over time.
The benefit is that you can now look up the start date in this table, perform a simple calculation on the WorkdaySequence column, and use that result to look up the date N workdays into the future. With the right indexes in place, this query is highly efficient.
For your problem, the following query can be used:
SELECT T.*, E.Date AS EndDate, PS.Date AS StartPaymentDate
FROM TestData T
JOIN Calendar S
    ON S.Date = T.StartDate
JOIN Calendar E
    ON E.WorkdaySequence = S.ThisOrNextWorkdaySequence + T.BufferDate
JOIN Calendar PS
    ON PS.WorkdaySequence = E.WorkdaySequence + 1
;

If you prefer, you can wrap the workday calculation up in a function.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AddWorkdays(@Date DATE, @Days INT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT TOP 1 E.Date
        FROM Calendar S
        JOIN Calendar E
            ON E.WorkdaySequence = S.ThisOrNextWorkdaySequence + @Days
        WHERE S.Date = @Date
    );
END

Your query then reduces to:
SELECT
    *,
    dbo.AddWorkdays(T.StartDate, T.BufferDate) AS EndDate,
    dbo.AddWorkdays(T.StartDate, T.BufferDate + 1) AS StartPaymentDate
FROM TestData T;

Because the function body is a single select statement, SQL server can inline any references into the caller's execution plan as a set operation. This is important if you expect to query more than a few rows at a time and care about efficiency.
Results:



StartDate
BufferDate
EndDate
StartPaymentDate




2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10


2024-12-24
3
2024-12-30
2024-12-31



For debugging purposes, these results can also be joined back into the calendar again to show all dates between StartDate and StartPaymentDate along with information showing the date logic progression - similar to what you posted in your original question.



StartDate
BufferDate
EndDate
StartPaymentDate
Date
DayOfWeek
DayType
WorkdayCount
Description
Remarks




2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-08-30
Friday
Workday
0
null
null


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-08-31
Saturday
Weekend
null
null
null


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-01
Sunday
Weekend Holiday
null
Happy New Year
Counted in system weekend


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-02
Monday
Holiday
null
Happy New Year Replacement
Datedadd = +1


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-03
Tuesday
Workday
1
null
null


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-04
Wednesday
Workday
2
null
null


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-05
Thursday
Holiday
null
Holiday 1
Datedadd = +1


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-06
Friday
Workday
3
null
null


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-07
Saturday
Weekend
null
null
null


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-08
Sunday
Weekend
null
null
null


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-09
Monday
Holiday
null
Holiday 2
Datedadd = +1


2024-08-30
3
2024-09-06
2024-09-10
2024-09-10
Tuesday
Workday
4
null
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Complicated issue, simple solution
Here is a Holiday table and a scalar type of user-defined-function (UDF) to solve your problem.
Table: Holidays other than weekly holidays will kept here. The structure will be as your holiday description.
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHoliDay](
        [HDate] [date] NULL,
        [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Days] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Remarks] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) 

Primarily the following data added to this table as per your description. Regular update of this data will make the function live.
INSERT INTO tblHoliday(HDate, Description, Days, Remarks) 
VALUES
('01-Sep-2024','HPN','Sunday','Counted in system weekend'),
('02-Sep-2024','HPNR','Monday','Dateadd=+1'),
('05-Sep-2024','Holiday 1','Thursday','Dateadd=+1'),
('09-Sep-2024','Holiday 2','Monday','Dateadd=+1'),
('25-Dec-2024','National Day','Wednesday','Dateadd=+1'),
('25-Dec-2024','Christmas Day','Wednesday','Dateadd=0 as same holiday'),
('01-Jan-2025','HPN','Wednesday','Dateadd=+1')

UDF: The scalar user defined function does two simple works.

It increased the date as required by the UDF parameter
Checked date with hard coded weekend (Saturday and Sunday) and declared holidays in table [tblHoliday]. If it found the day as holiday or weekend it advanced the date by one day. This SQL Server user defined function (UDF) is itself enough to understand.

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TargetDate (@ForwardDays INT , @BaseDate Date)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @WD VARCHAR(15)
    DECLARE @GetDate Date
    DECLARE @Counter INT
    DECLARE @RecNumb INT
    SET @Counter = @ForwardDays 
    SET @GetDate = @BaseDate

    WHILE ( @Counter >0)
    BEGIN
        SET @GetDate = DateAdd(day,1,@GetDate)
        SET @WD = DateName(WeekDay,@GetDate)
        IF Not (@WD='Saturday' OR @WD = 'Sunday') 
            BEGIN
                --Checking whether the @GetDate is declared as holiday
                SET @RecNumb = (SELECT count(*) FROM tblHoliDay WHERE HDate = @GetDate)
                if @RecNumb = 0 
                BEGIN
                    SET @Counter=@Counter-1
                END
            END
    END
   RETURN (@GetDate)
END

How will this function work?
This function can be called from any SQL Statement. look into the following examples
SELECT dbo.TargetDate(3,'30-Aug-2024') as StartDate, 
dbo.TargetDate(4,'30-Aug-2024') as StartPaymentDate 

The output will be



StartDate
StartPaymentDate




2024-09-06
2024-09-10



and
SELECT dbo.TargetDate(3,'24-Dec-2024') as StartDate, 
dbo.TargetDate(4,'24-Dec-2024') as StartPaymentDate 

The output will be



StartDate
StartPaymentDate




2024-12-30
2024-12-31



This sample work is implemented on SQL Server 2016.
Thanks.

We can create a list (table) of the next few days (in the example @BuferDate+10) and put the signs "day off" or "holiday" on them.
After that, we will calculate which of the working days we need.
There work_dn is work days count from StartDate to current date (dt).
Calculated as sum(work days)over(...)-1.
For work days and weekend days, used datename(dw,dt) function, to eliminate @datefirst settings.
And  work_dn=(@BuferDate+0) -> EndDate and work_dn=(@BuferDate+1) ->StartPaymentDate.
See example
Simple request.
There  parameters StartDate and BuferDate
declare @StartDate date='2024-08-30';
declare @BuferDate int=3;

select @StartDate StartDate
  ,max(case when work_dn=(@BuferDate+0) then dt end) EndDate
  ,max(case when work_dn=(@BuferDate+1) then dt end) StartPaymentDate
from(
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by work_dn order by dt)rn
from(
select a.* ,datename(dw,dt) dw
    ,sum(case when datename(dw,dt) in('Saturday','Sunday') or h.date is not null then 0 
        else 1 end)over( order by dt)-1 work_dn
  ,h.*
  from(
     select *,dateadd(day,value,@StartDate) dt,value daynum
     from generate_series(0,10+@BuferDate) dn
   )a
  left join Holiday h on h.Date=a.dt
 )b 
 where b.work_dn between (@BuferDate+0) and (@BuferDate+1)
)c where rn=1
;

Result is



StartDate
EndDate
StartPaymentDate




2024-08-30
2024-09-06
2024-09-10



Example for expanded table.



id
StartDate
dt
daynum
dw
work_dn
Holiday
Description
rn




1
2024-08-30
2024-08-30
0
Friday
0
null
null
1


1
2024-08-30
2024-08-31
1
Saturday
0
null
null
2


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-01
2
Sunday
0
2024-09-01
Happy New Year
3


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-02
3
Monday
0
2024-09-02
Happy New Year Replacement
4


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-03
4
Tuesday
1
null
null
1


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-04
5
Wednesday
2
null
null
1


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-05
6
Thursday
2
2024-09-05
Holiday 1
2


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-06
7
Friday
3
null
null
1


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-07
8
Saturday
3
null
null
2


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-08
9
Sunday
3
null
null
3


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-09
10
Monday
3
2024-09-09
Holiday 2
4


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-10
11
Tuesday
4
null
null
1


1
2024-08-30
2024-09-11
12
Wednesday
5
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-24
0
Tuesday
0
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-25
1
Wednesday
0
2024-12-25
National Day
2


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-25
1
Wednesday
0
2024-12-25
Christmas Day
3


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-26
2
Thursday
1
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-27
3
Friday
2
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-28
4
Saturday
2
null
null
2


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-29
5
Sunday
2
null
null
3


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-30
6
Monday
3
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-31
7
Tuesday
4
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2025-01-01
8
Wednesday
4
2025-01-01
Happy New Year
2


2
2024-12-24
2025-01-02
9
Thursday
5
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2025-01-03
10
Friday
6
null
null
1


2
2024-12-24
2025-01-04
11
Saturday
6
null
null
2


2
2024-12-24
2025-01-05
12
Sunday
6
null
null
3



There we use Holiday table



Date
Description
Days
Remarks




2024-09-01
Happy New Year
Sunday
Counted in system weekend


2024-09-02
Happy New Year Replacement
Monday
Datedadd = +1


2024-09-05
Holiday 1
Thursday
Datedadd = +1


2024-09-09
Holiday 2
Monday
Datedadd = +1


2024-12-25
National Day
Wednesday
Datedadd = +1


2024-12-25
Christmas Day
Wesneday
Datedadd = 0 (because 2 same holiday falls on weekday will be counted as 1 holiday)


2025-01-01
Happy New Year
Wednesday
Datedadd = +1



Example for table
create table test (id int,StartDate date);
insert into test values
 (1,'2024-08-30')
,(2,'2024-12-24')
;

Query for test table
declare @BuferDate int=3;
select id,max(StartDate) StartDate
  ,max(case when work_dn=(@BuferDate+0) then dt end) EndDate
  ,max(case when work_dn=(@BuferDate+1) then dt end) StartPaymentDate
from(
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by id,work_dn order by dt)rn
from(
select a.* ,datename(dw,dt) dw
  ,sum(case when datename(dw,dt) in('Saturday','Sunday') or h.date is not null then 0 else 1 end)
       over(partition by id order by dt)-1 work_dn
  ,h.*
from(
select *,dateadd(day,value,StartDate) dt,value daynum
from test
cross apply generate_series(0,12) dn
)a
left join Holiday h on h.Date=a.dt
)b 
where b.work_dn between (@BuferDate+0) and (@BuferDate+1)
)c where rn=1
group by id
;




id
StartDate
EndDate
StartPaymentDate




1
2024-08-30
2024-09-06
2024-09-10


2
2024-12-24
2024-12-30
2024-12-31



fiddle
